# Vbs Script To Send Email WITHOUT Password

Tags: email, vbscript, passwords, send

I am actually trying to make something in my project to send emails every time from my account to mine when the user runs the application , However I keep on changing my account's password regulary so it can cause problem to me , Any way to send email without the password of my account ? . Thanks :)

This is the url of my script - http://pastebin.com/Nngh39p1

Will I need to install something  to make it work on newer versions such as windows/7/8 ? And if there is any alternative to the same way in vbs pls help

Comment: What are you using to send e-mail? `CDO` can use NTLM credentials.

Comment: Hello A question is cdo function avlaible for all? I mean it gives me error

Comment: Submit a new question and post the code you're using along with the error you're receiving. Or, just edit your question above.

Comment: Done added the question along with the url of my script

Answer (score 0):

Give this a look see... 
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm/
It doesn't use your mail program.

Comment: Actually I need it for windows 7/8